# Right click -> New Folder on macos finder's column view is very inconsistent

Tags: macos, finder

[image: Screenshot 1]

I expect that when I right click an empty spot in the middle column and select "New Folder," the untitled folder will appear in the middle column, and similarly, it will show on the right right column when I right click an empty spot on the right column and select new folder (see Screenshot 1 above).

But half the time when I right click a column and try to create a new folder, the untitled folder appears in the root of the directory (the left column, see Screenshot 2, below). I don't understand what mac is doing here, but is there a way to make it behave consistently? I just want this thing to open the folder wherever my cursor is.

The other questions I found on SE about this UI bug were dealing list view, and said that I should double click the folder to have it "displayed"; I double clicked the folder icon and the right most column and it still behaves inconsistently.

[image: Screenshot 2]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've never thought of this as really the most 'obvious' behaviour, but it is consistent.
It makes the new folder at the point the window is 'mounted', not your current place within that hierarchy.

If you open Documents in column view, then drill down another couple of levels, the window itself still considers its 'root/mount point' to be Documents & will make new folders there. This perhaps easier to visualise in List View, or even more so in Icon View, where the window title is where the folder will be made.

To create a folder inside your specific sub-level, you need to promote it to current 'root/mount'. Double-clicking the folder will promote it.

<sup>I have never know the correct terms for these points, they are of course not true mount points nor roots, but you can consider they each temporarily behave as though they were.</sup>

In your example image, once you have confirmed the name for the currently being renamed 'untitled folder, then double-clicking either that folder or the empty column to its right will promote it & your next folder will be generated in that empty column.

Comment: So if I want to create a folder in the "R/" directory in the first image I double click "R?" and if I want to create another folder in the "mypac" directory, I double click "mypac?"

Comment: That's the idea, yup. Try it.

Comment: I swear this only works half the time. I double click the folder I want the untitled folder to be created in, and it will create the untitled folder in the parent directory.